# XDocument load XML in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I have this code will run when the page is navigated to.

```
private XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("APPSDATA.xml");
```

It run Ok with the first run, but when I back to the main page and go back to this page again,
an error occurred. I dont understand why, anyone can help me with this ? Tks

> {System.Xml.XmlException: Cannot find file 'APPSDATA.xml' in the application xap package.

Comment: tks, I'm checking it out :) Seem work

Comment: It worked :D answer this Question, i'll mark u :)

Comment: I did :-) glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While loading, you should reference it to the isolated storage store where the file exists

```
private XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(store.OpenFile("APPSDATA.xml", FileMode.Open));
```